# Skipping the Home Realm Discovery Page for ADFS authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, openid-connect, adfs

I am using ASP.net MVC open id connecto to authenticate user with ADFS. Whenever I hit application url It redirects to ADFS Home Realm Discovery page where we see multiple IDP (Client Accounts) to sign in.
How could we by pass this page and go directly to repsective IDP's login page depending on subdomain in URL.

For eg, if I have a couple of clients (tenant) 1. Cloud Network Pvt Ltd 2.Cloud ddns and I could see a couple of on-premise AD. If the user hits "cloudddns.myapp.com" then it should show on that client's ADFS sign in page.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can map a RP to an IDP.

e.g. all users of RP A will use the Fabrikam IDP to authenticate.

The command is:

Set-AdfsRelyingPartyTrust -TargetName "RP A" -ClaimsProviderName @("Fabrikam","Active Directory")

Would that work for you?

Comment: Also note that ADFS also supports UPN suffix based routing as well. You can find more info on this at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/home-realm-discovery-customization