# Skipping the Home Realm Discovery Page in ADFS for OpenID Connect RP

Tags: openid-connect, adfs, adfs4.0

[Skipping the Home Realm Discovery Page for ADFS authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54141112/skipping-the-home-realm-discovery-page-for-adfs-authentication)

The post from above should cover my case. But it still without an answer. 
I can skip HRD page for registered RP using ***homeRealm*** or ***whr*** parameter. So With registered Relay Paries all works well. But In the same time we have several applications with OpenId Connect authentication flow. And I don't fully understand how can I tune ADFS to skip Home Realm Discovery page for these applications. They included to Application Groups. And We can see a list of them using ***Get-AdfsServerApplication***.

Is that really that there is no settings for ADFS that allow clients with OpenID Connect to forward through the Home Realm Discovery Page, since this is done for Azure: [HRD Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-authentication-for-federated-users-portal#set-hrd-policy)?

Update: It should cover the case when third-party services should be added to federation, whose requests cannot be controlled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is.  It looks like this:

```
#Set-AdfsWebApiApplication -TargetName "NativeWPF - Web API" -ClaimsProviderName @("Active Directory")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

"login_hint:
Can be used to pre-fill the username/email address field of the sign in page for the user, if you know their username ahead of time. Often apps will use this parameter during re-authentication, having already extracted the username from a previous sign-in using the upn claim from id_token

domain_hint:
If included, it will skip the domain-based discovery process that user goes through on the sign in page, leading to a slightly more streamlined user experience"

as per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/overview/ad-fs-openid-connect-oauth-flows-scenarios).

Comment: Thanks a lot for moderation, I'm new to English, and thanks for response. The fact is that this problem, in my case, is typical for third-party clients that I do not manage, and they only support a certain number of parameters. I noticed the command: `Set-AdfsRelyingPartyTrust -TargetName claimapp -ClaimsProviderName @ ("Fabrikam", "Active Directory")`, if used with one parameter, HRD Page will also be skipped. However, I did not find anything like this for OpenID Connect. Intuitively, it seemed like it should be.